# AADSTS700023: Client assertion audience claim does not match Realm issuer error in ConfidentialClientApplication

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I'm successfully getting an authorization code with a call to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
but when I try to acquire the token with that code with a call to

confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, new[] {"files.read.all"});

I get an error of
AADSTS700023: Client assertion audience claim does not match Realm issuer

I'm creating the ConfidentialClientApplication with a call to:
new ConfidentialClientApplication("Same client id as the authorize call", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0", "same redirect url as the authorize call", correct client credentials, null, null);

In the portal "App registration (preview)" I have it set to allow all kinds of Microsoft accounts, AD and outlook.com etc...

Since I'm using common as the authority for both calls I expected this to work, ideas why it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

I solved exactly the same issue on my code. In my JWT payload the `aud` was incorrect. That's pretty much what the error states.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `aud` points towards the exact endpoint you are trying to get the token from.

So if your endpoint is `https://login.microsoftonline.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/oauth2/token` the value of `aud` should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/oauth2/token` as well.